# data types to store large numbers in C

Tags: c

I want to store a number `"x"` where `0<=x<=(10^18)`.

Which datatype should be used in C for storing such a large number?

I used "long int" but it's not working..

Comment: use `uint64_t` with `#include <stdint.h>`, `#include <inttypes.h>`

Comment: Can this be question be "de-duplicated"?  This question involves "medium sized integers" and I'd say the correct answer is "`uint64_t`"; while the pretend duplicate question is completely different and does involve big numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Use `unsigned long long int`. It is supported in C99 or later, and as a compiler extension in some pre-1999 compilers. and it must be able to hold at least `1.8 * 10^19` values.